# How to find neighbouring element of mother element (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I'm clicking on `li` element, I want to work with `elem2` and it must to work with `$(this)` because I have a lot wrappers.

```
<div class='wrapper'>
   <div class='elem1'>
      <ul>
         <li></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class='elem2'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly you want ? on clicking of li element, you want to select all child element of wrapper ? or you just want to select all siblings of elem1 i.e.e elem2 elem3 etc..

Comment: Try `$(this).closest('div').next()`. Would help a lot if you gave more details as in [ask]

Comment: last one :) i just want to select elem2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this jQuery:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    var elem2 = $(this).closest("div").next();
    //Do stuff
})
```

Or:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    var elem2 = $(".elem2");
    //Do stuff
})
```

Comment: what if i have one more `div` between `elem1` and `elem2` ?

Comment: Then use the second example

Comment: ok, if i have a lot tags with class `elem2`, but I need to work with `elem2` of this `li` ?